# Prove that $\Bbb R^2$ is a vector space given these definitions of addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $x = (x_{1}, x_{2})$, $y= (y_{1}, y_{2})$, $x, y \in \Bbb R^{2}$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$.
I have to prove that $\Bbb R^{2}$ is a vector space with addition defined as
$$ (x_{1},x_{2}) + (y_{1},y_{2}) = (x_{1}+y_{1},x_{2}+y_{2})$$
and scalar multiplication defined as
$$ \alpha x = \alpha(x_{1}, x_{2}) = (\alpha x_{1}, x_{2})$$
I was able to prove most of the properties of a vector space, but I'm struggling to prove that
$$(\alpha + \beta) x = \alpha x + \beta x$$
I can see that $(\alpha + \beta)x = (\alpha + \beta) (x_{1},x_{2}) = ((\alpha + \beta)x_{1}, x_{2})$, but I don't know how to proceed. How can I go about this?

Comment: You should check that again, $(\alpha + \beta)(x_1, x_2) = ((\alpha + \beta)x_1, (\alpha + \beta)x_2)$ per the definition of scalar multiplication.

Comment: Note that $\alpha, \beta, x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, so you can use the distributive law in the ordered field $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $(\alpha+\beta)x_1 = \alpha x_1 + \beta x_1$.

Comment: I have to use the definition of scalar multiplication I was given, in which the scalar only multiplies the first entry of the vector. Using the distributive law in the ordered field I get that $(\alpha + \beta)x = (\alpha x_{1} + \beta x_{1}, x_{2})$, but how does that equal $\alpha x + \beta x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false.  The distributive property fails.

$(2x_1, x_2)=2 \cdot (x_1. x_2)=(1+1) \cdot (x_1, x_2)\\ \neq 1 \cdot (x_1, x_2) + 1 \cdot (x_1, x_2) = (x_1, x_2) + (x_1+x_2)=(2x_1, 2x_2).$

More easily, $0 \cdot (x_1, x_2)= (0, x_2) \neq (0, 0).$